# bower packages with submodules polymer

Tags: web, npm, polymer, bower, bower-install

We are developing a toolset of components which are available through bower. When we looked at the Polymer components we noticed that they make use of 'bower install **Polymer**/*Module*'

My question is how do they manage to work with these "submodules" in Bower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user/package` format is not specific to Polymer, it is a feature of the [`bower install` command](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install). It is a shorthand for a Git repository, and Bower defaults to GitHub.

`bower install polymer/core-icon`

is the same as

`bower install https://github.com/polymer/core-icon.git`